# UnderscoreJS _.every for nulls

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Seems like null should equal null. So why does

```
_.every([null], _.identity);
false

_.any([null], _.identity);
false
```

This result makes more sense (in my head)

```
null === _.identity(null);
true
```

Comment: you don't compare null to null, you compare null to true, which is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`every` is not doing any comparisons, it just expects a truthy/falsy value to be returned. `null` is falsy. From the MDN on the built-in `every`:

> The every method executes the provided callback function once for each
>   element present in the array until it finds one where callback returns
>   a falsy value (a value that becomes false when converted to a
>   Boolean). If such an element is found, the every method immediately
>   returns false. Otherwise, if callback returned a true value for all
>   elements, every will return true.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 1):

According to the semantics of [`_.every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every) and [`_.any`](http://underscorejs.org/#some), those should come out `false`:

**Semantics.**

`_.every(arr, predicate) === true` iff ∀x ∈ arr: `predicate(x)`.

- In other words, the expression evaluates to `true` if and only if *every* element in `arr` satisfies the `predicate` (a function from expressions to truth-values).

`_.any(arr, predicate) === true` iff ∃x ∈ arr: `predicate(x)`.

- In other words, the expression evaluates to `true` if and only if *at least one* element in `arr` satisfies the `predicate`.

**Application.**

`_.every([null], _.identity)`

- ≡ `_.identity(null)`
- ≡ `null`
- ≡ `false`.

`_.any([null], _.identity)`

- ≡ `[null].some(_.identity)`
- ≡ `false` (since ¬∃x ∈ `{null}`: `_.identity(x)`).